# Implement Background Image (linked to website url) from external css file to html

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble referencing an external css program (specifically a background image from a url) into my html file. I was able to implement css internally, so the url linking to the website is not the problem. I have seen similar posts talking about similar situations, but I wasnt able to solve my problem from them. I am very new to this so I am guessing it's probably something very stupid and simple, but after several hours I must admit defeat and succumb to the all-knowing online community.
So, here is my Practice.css code:

```
body{
background-color: whitesmoke;
background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/1562/italian-landscape-mountains-nature.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 1400px 750px;}
```

Here is my Practice.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Practice.css"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

'CSS' is the name of the folder the Practice.css is in. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `<style>` tags around your `<link>` element.

Comment: I did and it still does not show up

Comment: is the `href` to the css correct? Its located in Desktop/ComputerPrograms/CSS/Practice.css

Comment: and the html file is in Desktop/ComputerPrograms/HTML/Practice.css

Comment: Check the browser's console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **css** file can be anywhere else on the web. But when you're dealing with file referenced directly on the computer you might have some problems.

To make sure everything works fine try to make sure your css folder is no the same root as your html index file.

BUT your specific case your link to css should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Practice.css"/>
```

Once the HTML folder and CSS folder share the same root the html file and css file are disconnected directly. The path should point first to the root where the HTML and CSS folder are which is **../** then point to the css folder and file **../CSS/Practice.css**

Answer (score 0):

I can guess by the comments that your .html and .css files are in HTML and CSS directories respectively. Both of these are in the directory ComputerPrograms. Hence, the reference to .css from your html page is wrong. It should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Practice.css"/>
```